# When should I consider a system backup over a normal database backup?

Tags: magento-1.9, database

I want to patch my site, but I don't know what kind of backup I should create. Is a simple database backup enough?

Comment: please refer http://www.snapfast.com/blog/magento-backup-methods/

Comment: If you are patching your site, means you are changing the code so do a full system backup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you to take complete system backup.

you can take all kinds of backup by system > tools > Backup  from backend

```
system Backup = Files + media + database backup

    Database backup - only database backup
```